# Multidimensional associative array in $_POST returns only last value

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, superglobals

I've tryed to make a multidimensional associative array but only one value is returned in the $_post.

See working example:

```
<html>
<?php
    if (isset( $_POST['form_submit'])){
        $Step=$_POST['form_submit'];
        If ($Step>1) $Step=0;
    }else{
        $Step=0;
    }
switch ($Step) {
    case 0:
        echo '
        <form method="post">
        <input name="Txt[First]" type="text"/>
        <input name="Txt[First][Second]" type="text"/>
        <input name="Txt[First][Second][Third]" type="text"/>
        <input name="Txt[First][Second][Third][Fourth]" type="text"/>
        <button type="submit" name="form_submit" value="'.($Step+1).'">submit</button>
        </form>';
    break;

    case 1:
        echo '<br/></br>print_r($_POST):<br/>';
        print_r($_POST);
    break;
}
?>
</html>
```

**edit**

if I add "[]" in the end of each input name I'll have all the values but in the wrong way:
$_POST wil be like:

```
Array ( 
    [Txt] => Array ( 
        [First] => Array ( 
            [0] => one 
            [Second] => Array ( 
                [0] => two 
                [Third] => Array ( 
                    [0] => three 
                    [Fourth] => Array (
                        [0] => four 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

but I need something like:

```
$_Post[First] => one  
$_Post[First][Second] => two  
$_Post[First][Second][Third] => three
```

...and so on

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: Of course, because you are overwriting `$_POST[Txt][First]`, which is a string value, by then "appending" a new key, `Second`, therefor replacing the existing string value with an array ...

Comment: @showdev You'll see it running the code and submitting the form

Comment: What array structure do you want? If you fill the inputs with `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` then what should the PHP array look like?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I need something like an xml (because I need to put values in an xml file)

Comment: Yes Correct, this is expected behavior.

Comment: You need to specify a key, `name="Txt[First][Foo]"`, or at least add another empty set of `[]`, `name="Txt[First][]"`, if you want the value of that field to "survive" the setting of the key `Second` which happens due to the next field.

Comment: _"I need something like an xml"_ - you'll need to be a bit more specific than that ... please edit the question to include a proper example of what array structure you want to find in $_POST.

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my question

Comment: What you say you need isn't possible.  A value can't be both a string and an array.

Comment: @PatrickQ Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: Not really.  You still haven't given an example of what you're ultimately trying to achieve.  You say you need "something like an xml", but you need to show _exactly_ what it is you're trying to produce and explain how that relates to filling out a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't possible. You can only have indexes in an array, but if `$_POST['Txt']['First']` is a string like `one` then it can't also be an array with `['Second']` index.

You can put the text of each level in a named element:

```
    <form method="post">
    <input name="Txt[First][text]" type="text"/>
    <input name="Txt[First][Second][text]" type="text"/>
    <input name="Txt[First][Second][Third][text]" type="text"/>
    <input name="Txt[First][Second][Third][Fourth][text]" type="text"/>
    <button type="submit" name="form_submit" value="'.($Step+1).'">submit</button>
    </form>';
```

Then the result will be:

```
$_Post['Txt'][First]['text'] => one  
$_Post['Txt'][First][Second]['text'] => two  
$_Post['Txt'][First][Second][Third]['text'] => three  
$_Post['Txt'][First][Second][Third][Fourth]['text'] => three
```

Comment: T'hanks. It's probably the only way